# Music Notation Recorder Debugging and Resolving

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, fft

I am currently trying to create an Android Application where a user pushes a button and the app listens to music, finds the tempo, collects the note information for each quarter note from the tempo by:

- Receiving the audio byte array.
- FFT (to find frequency)
- Use frequency to determine the note of that quarter note.
- Assigning that note to an array that will later be displayed as sheet music.

This is the code that I currently have done:

```
package com.tentmaker.musicnotationrecorder;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.analysis.FFT;

public class Record extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btnRecord;
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private static String mFileName = null;
    float[] fftArray;

    private boolean recording;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

    btnRecord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
    btnRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try{
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.recordButton:
                buttonEvent();
                return;
            default:
                return; 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void buttonEvent(){
    if(recording){
        startRecording();
        frequencyCollection();
        process(fft());
    }
    else if(!recording){
        stopRecording();
    }
}

public void startRecording(){
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "recording...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "prepare() failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    mRecorder.start();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void stopRecording() {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private float[] fft() {
    int fs = 8374;
    int N = fftArray.length;
    float[] fft_cpx, tmpr, tmpi;
    float[] res = new float[N / 2];
    // float[] mod_spec =new float[array.length/2];
    float[] real_mod = new float[N];
    float[] imag_mod = new float[N];
    double[] real = new double[N];
    double[] imag = new double[N];
    double[] mag = new double[N];
    double[] phase = new double[N];
    float[] new_array = new float[N];
    // Zero Pad signal
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (i < fftArray.length) {
            new_array[i] = fftArray[i];
        } 
        else {
            new_array[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    FFT fft = new FFT(N, 8373);

    fft.forward(new_array);
    fft_cpx = fft.getSpectrum();
    tmpi = fft.getImaginaryPart();
    tmpr = fft.getRealPart();
    for (int i = 0; i < new_array.length; i++) {
        real[i] = (double) tmpr[i];
        imag[i] = (double) tmpi[i];

        mag[i] = Math.sqrt((real[i] * real[i]) + (imag[i] * imag[i]));
        phase[i] = Math.atan2(imag[i], real[i]);

        /**** Reconstruction ****/
        real_mod[i] = (float) (mag[i] * Math.cos(phase[i]));
        imag_mod[i] = (float) (mag[i] * Math.sin(phase[i]));

        double freq = (double)i*(double)fs/(double)N;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                       "Frequency: "+ Double.toString(freq) + 
                       "Magnitude: "+ Double.toString(mag[i]), 
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    fft.inverse(real_mod, imag_mod, res);
    return res;

}

private void process(float[] fft){

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void frequencyCollection(){
    int channel_config = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
    int format = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int sampleSize = 8000;
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleSize, channel_config, format);
    AudioRecord audioInput = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, sampleSize, channel_config, format, bufferSize);

    byte[] audioBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    audioInput.startRecording();
    audioInput.read(audioBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

    float[] fftTempArray = new float[bufferSize];
    for (int i=0; i<bufferSize; i++)
    {
        fftTempArray[i] = audioBuffer[i];
    }
    fftArray = fftTempArray;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.record, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I am pretty sure most of this would not work. Right now I am trying to understand and complete the code where it receives the byte array and sends it through the FFT. After that, I want to take what it got from the FFT and find the maximum frequency of that specific section (quarter note) so that I can do the rest (of which I know how to do). How should I complete these steps?

Answer (score 0):

These steps won't work for most actual live music, as most musical pitches are represented by a very complicated sequence of FFT frequencies (much more than one maximum frequency per "quarter note").  Look in [mirex-IR](http://www.music-ir.org/mirex/wiki/MIREX_HOME) for a lot of graduate research papers on possibly how to solve your problem in a limited proportion of cases.

Comment: Right now I want to see if I could do such a thing as this with a simple melody composed of single notes. Would this be possible using these steps or is something even this simple requiring of a graduate level project?

Comment: Might be reasonable if your melody is produced by a sinewave generator driven by a strict tempo timer.

Comment: What then would you recommend that I do?